# Woocommerce Show / Hide Checkout Fields based on shipping method and making it a required field when shown

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am trying to show `delivery_datetime_field` checkout field on woocommerce only when `shipping_method_0_local_pickup_plus` is checked on the checkout page.

I'm trying to build that function by basing it on [this guide](http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-hide-checkout-fields-for-virtual-products/) for hiding checkout fields for virtual products.

However, I keep getting Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in the checkout page.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'woo_remove_billing_checkout_fields' );
function woo_remove_billing_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
if ($chosen_methods[0] == 'shipping_method_0_local_pickup_plus'){
if( woo_cart_has_virtual_product() == true ) {
    unset($fields['billing']['delivery_datetime_field']);
}   
return $fields;
}
 if( count($products) == $virtual_products )
$has_virtual_products = true;  
return $has_virtual_products;
 }
```

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: The problem is this line: `if ($chosen_methods[0] == 'shipping_method_0_local_pickup_plus'){` as `$chosen_methods` is not defined…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do it via editing a little on the local pickup plus plugin, here if anyone needs it:

```
if ( localPickupPlusOnly && ! $( '#ship-to-different-address-checkbox' ).prop( 'checked' ) ) {
                        // only local pickup plus is being used, hide the shipping address fields
                        $( '#shiptobilling, #ship-to-different-address' ).hide();
                        $( '#delivery_datetime_field' ).show();
                        $( '#shiptobilling, #ship-to-different-address' ).parent().find( 'h3' ).hide();
                        $( '.shipping_address' ).hide();
                    } else {
                        // some other shipping method is being used, show the shipping address fields
                        $( '#shiptobilling, #ship-to-different-address' ).show();
                        $( '#delivery_datetime_field' ).hide();
                        $( '#shiptobilling, #ship-to-different-address' ).parent().find( 'h3' ).show();
                        if ( ( $( '#shiptobilling input' ).length > 0 && ! $( '#shiptobilling input' ).is( ':checked' ) ) || $( '#ship-to-different-address input' ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
                            $( '.shipping_address' ).show();
                        }
                    }
```

*The only issue now is that, though hidden, will not checkout if `delivery_datetime_field` is enabled as a required field.* I only want the field to be required if local pickup is chosen at checkout.

If anyone is looking for a solution:

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'local_pickup_disable' );
function local_pickup_disable( $local_pickup ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

    if( $chosen_shipping == 'local_pickup_plus' ) {
/**
 * Process the local_pickup checkout
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_local_pickup_process');

function my_custom_checkout_local_pickup_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['delivery_datetime'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please let us know when you plan to pick up your order by selecting a collection date.' ), 'error' );
    else
        /**
* Update the order meta with Pick Up question
**/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_pickup_field_update_order_meta', 10, 2);
function my_pickup_field_update_order_meta( $order_id, $posted ) {
    if ( $_POST['delivery_datetime'] ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_e_deliverydate', esc_attr($_POST['delivery_datetime']));
    }
}
/**
 * Add the Pick Up custom fields to order emails
 **/
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_pickup_checkout_field_order_meta_keys');
function my_pickup_checkout_field_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
    $label_name = __("Pick Up Date","delivery_datetime");
    $keys[$label_name] = "Pick Up Date";
    return $keys;
}   

}
```

Comment: This solution not working. And you are not supposed to edit the plugin directly.